# Batch-imported data not available in Neo4j until server restart

Tags: neo4j

I'm using batch-import to load a very small graph (5 nodes; 3 rels) into neo4j 1.9.1. The import showed success, yet the data is not available through webadmin or REST queries until I restart the neo4j server. Very strange. Can somebody enlight me?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have the server running if you to batchimport, since both systems are accessing the same files, and having the server running might corrupt your DB. First to batchimport, then start your server to get correct numbers.